# Draw Dots like Matrix Structure on iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to Draw dots like a Matrix Structure in iphone sdk.

if i want generate dots columns and rows (like 2x2,3x3,4x4).

but i have no idea for this generation.

i want output like below image.

[image]

any help for example code or tutorial..!

Comment: In CG, dots are simple, but dotted lines are expensive.  Which are you trying to accomplish.

Comment: It would be better if you can elaborate this a litle more. For simple purpose, you simply can achieve this using Arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use this code ...

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect 
{
CGContextRef contextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextSetRGBFillColor(contextRef, 0, 0, 255, 0.1);
//CGContextSetRGBFillColor(contextRef, 0, 10, 200, 0.2);

CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(contextRef, 0, 0, 255, 0.5);

// Draw a circle (filled)
//CGContextFillEllipseInRect(contextRef, CGRectMake(100, 100, 25, 25));

// Draw a circle (border only)
CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(contextRef, CGRectMake(100, 100, 25, 25));



// Get the graphics context and clear it
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextClearRect(ctx, rect);



// Draw a green solid circle
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 0, 255, 0, 1);
CGContextFillEllipseInRect(ctx, CGRectMake(20, 50, 8, 8));

CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 0, 255, 0, 1);
CGContextFillEllipseInRect(ctx, CGRectMake(50, 50, 8, 8));

CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 0, 255, 0, 1);
CGContextFillEllipseInRect(ctx, CGRectMake(80, 50, 8, 8));

CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 0, 255, 0, 1);
CGContextFillEllipseInRect(ctx, CGRectMake(110, 50, 8, 8));

CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 0, 255, 0, 1);
CGContextFillEllipseInRect(ctx, CGRectMake(140, 50, 8, 8));

CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 0, 255, 0, 1);
CGContextFillEllipseInRect(ctx, CGRectMake(170, 50, 8, 8));



CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 0, 255, 0, 1);
CGContextFillEllipseInRect(ctx, CGRectMake(20, 100, 8, 8));

CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 0, 255, 0, 1);
CGContextFillEllipseInRect(ctx, CGRectMake(50, 100, 8, 8));

CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 0, 255, 0, 1);
CGContextFillEllipseInRect(ctx, CGRectMake(80, 100, 8, 8));

CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 0, 255, 0, 1);
CGContextFillEllipseInRect(ctx, CGRectMake(110, 100, 8, 8));

CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 0, 255, 0, 1);
CGContextFillEllipseInRect(ctx, CGRectMake(140, 100, 8, 8));

CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 0, 255, 0, 1);
CGContextFillEllipseInRect(ctx, CGRectMake(170, 100, 8, 8));


CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 0, 255, 0, 1);
CGContextFillEllipseInRect(ctx, CGRectMake(20, 150, 8, 8));

CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 0, 255, 0, 1);
CGContextFillEllipseInRect(ctx, CGRectMake(50, 150, 8, 8));

CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 0, 255, 0, 1);
CGContextFillEllipseInRect(ctx, CGRectMake(80, 150, 8, 8));

CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 0, 255, 0, 1);
CGContextFillEllipseInRect(ctx, CGRectMake(110, 150, 8, 8));

CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 0, 255, 0, 1);
CGContextFillEllipseInRect(ctx, CGRectMake(140, 150, 8, 8));

CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 0, 255, 0, 1);
CGContextFillEllipseInRect(ctx, CGRectMake(170, 150, 8, 8));


CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 0, 255, 0, 1);
CGContextFillEllipseInRect(ctx, CGRectMake(20, 200, 8, 8));

CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 0, 255, 0, 1);
CGContextFillEllipseInRect(ctx, CGRectMake(50, 200, 8, 8));

CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 0, 255, 0, 1);
CGContextFillEllipseInRect(ctx, CGRectMake(80, 200, 8, 8));

CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 0, 255, 0, 1);
CGContextFillEllipseInRect(ctx, CGRectMake(110, 200, 8, 8));

CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 0, 255, 0, 1);
CGContextFillEllipseInRect(ctx, CGRectMake(140, 200, 8, 8));

CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 0, 255, 0, 1);
CGContextFillEllipseInRect(ctx, CGRectMake(170, 200, 8, 8));
}
```

Your Output shows like
[image]

Comment: your code is ok but i want to generate columns and rows dynamically...!

Comment: Use 'for' loop to generate dynamically. try ur self. using this code.

Comment: try this 
int i=7;
 int n=0;
 int m=0;
 for (int x=0; x<i; x++)
 {
  for (int j=0; j<i; j++) 
  {
   CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 0, 255, 0, 1);
   CGContextFillEllipseInRect(ctx, CGRectMake(20+n, 50+m, 8, 8));
   n=n+30;
  }
  n=0;
  m=m+50;
 }

'i' is ur given value.

Comment: how to call draw rect function in myuiview

Answer (score 6):

A simple Solution would be:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
  int n = 12;         // row and column count
  int padding = 5;    // distance beetween dots
  float radius = MIN((rect.size.width-(n+1)*padding)/(n*2), (rect.size.height-(n+1)*padding)/(n*2)); // radius depending on rect size

  CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
  CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]); // background color
  CGContextFillRect(context, rect); // setting background color

  CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]); // dot color

  for (int y = 0; y<n; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x<n; x++) {
      CGContextAddArc(context, padding+radius+(padding+radius*2)*x, padding+radius+(padding+radius*2)*y, radius, 0, M_PI*2, 0); // adding dot path
      CGContextFillPath(context); // drawing dot path
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You simple have to implement a subclass of UIView and overwrite the drawRect method with this implementation.

Comment: you must not call drawRect by your self, drawRect will be called by the application automatically as soon as the View is displayed on the screen.